# convert Ethernet router into integration gateway

Tags: linux, networking, router, ip, ethernet

I need to integrate to an Ethernet proprietary network.  It is IP based but doesn't implement TCP.

I need a router which will poll devices on this network, and periodically post the data using probably HTTP to a Linux server.  It will probably also need to send its MAC address to the server to so the server may identify the source of the data.  The integration router ideally will have an embedded web server which will allow for configuration.

Am I able to take a typical router and replace the firmware which something suitable to my needs?  Any recommendations for which programming language to use to create the firmware, or which router hardware to start off with?  Would you recommend starting off with a router which utilizes Linux?

Comment: We don't even know what 'proprietary' network you're talking about exactly.

Comment: can't use HTTP without TCP.

Comment: @geewee  Technically, it isn't proprietary, but didn't want to overly complicate the question.  It is BACnet.

Comment: @FrankThomas  TCP will be used for the HTTP communication, just not the proprietary/BACnet side.

Comment: BACNet is inherently defined at layers 2 and below. it does not know what a router is. In fact, due to the wide variety of Layer-1/2 implementations it supports, there isn't even such a thing as a MAC address. Your theoretical router woudl have to be programmed to act as one of the 54 types of objects defined in the BACNet standard in order to participate. See here for a list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BACnet That said, the general idea you have for flashing a comercial router with new firmware is probably doomed from conception, as you would need hardware knowledge for that model.

Comment: @FrankThomas  Thank you for your comment.  The part about the MAC address would just be used with the HTTP communication between the router and the server.  Why would hardware knowledge be needed?  I thought that a PC with appropriate software could communicate to a BACNet IP controller.  Couldn't the required software be implemented in the router?  Thanks!

Comment: ahh, well if you are using a general purpose PC rather than a hardware router, it would be Software, not Firmware. Firmware generally requires a knowledge of the signals the hardware provides, but software provides more abstraction, so its a differant kind of thing. Yes you could probably write the software you need, provided you understand the APIs your choosen OS exposes to you.

Comment: @FrankThomas  And is it possible that given one understands the BACNet API/etc, one could write the appropriate software and operate it on an applicable router?  Thanks again

Comment: a commercial router appliance? not without either the cooperation of the manufacturer or extensive reverse engineering.  In that case, I'd look for a ddwrt compatible router, so you can target ddwrt as an abstraction rather than trying to target the vendor specific hardware. but we are getting way out of the "on-topic" zone for superuser. you would probably have better luck somewhere else, since your question relies on hardware and programming.

Comment: @FrankThomas  Thanks again for your help.  Tried posting elsewhere (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31480268/create-new-router-firmware-to-re-purpose-the-device), and am getting based as a hacker :(